# Django group by to find the count

Tags: python, django

I have models as given below.

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

All i need is to get the count of pages with each country. i.e,

{country1: 3, country2: 4}

(Country specific page count)

Is it possible to get the count of the pages based on the country foreign key as shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate with a count:

```
pages = Page.objects.annotate(num_countries=Count('country'))
pages[0].num_countries  # 3
pages[1].num_countries  # 4
```

There are [plenty of details and examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) about this in the aggregation API docs.